# Tasks in Ada statement 'accept start do ' is not completing it all execution?

Tags: task, ada

Tasks in Ada  'accept start do ' statement is not completing its all execution ?

accept start do

Here 'do' keyword force compiler to finish  all the execution mention  between do and end keyword but why in below code its not happen ?why it is  printing other task body i.e first(task name) not its own task(i.e start) in the below code? please help me to understand where i went wrong?

```
procedure main is
   task first is
      entry start;
   end first;

   task body first is
   begin
      accept start ;   -- i am not using do here

      put_line("first");
      put_line("first");
      put_line("first");
   end first;

   task second is
      entry start;
   end second;

   task body second is
   begin
      accept start do -- here 'do' keyword will force compile to finish all the execution between keyword 'do' and end? but why it is mixing statement of task first? 
         for i in 1..10 loop
            put_line("second");
         end loop;
      end start;
   end second;

begin
   first.start;
   second.start;
end main;

   output-
   second
   second
   second
   second
   first   -- why first get printed between before completing second?
   first
   first
   second
   second
   second
   second
   second
   second
```

Note-every time its give different o/p i was expecting if task second gets activated first then it should first complete all the statement between do and end  it should not print other task statement till second gets finish then its should go for other task

Answer (score 5):

After `first.start` is accepted, `first` is ready to output a line whenever it gets a processor, while `main` carries on and calls `second.start`.

After `second.start` is accepted, `second` outputs its 10 lines before returning control to `main`.

But, what happens if deep within the Ada runtime system, or even the operating system, it turns out that `put_line` involves blocking?

In that case, `second` is blocked, so `first` is free to carry on and output one of its lines. At which point `first` is likely to be blocked again, so `second` gets a chance ...

So it seems that your OS (and mine - Mac OS X) block, or at any rate can block, inside `put_line`.

Overall, the fact is that standard output - which is what you are accessing via `put` or `put_line` - is a shared resource which you are accessing from two tasks. The Ada language ([ARM 9(8)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-9.html#p8)) says

> tasks can communicate indirectly by reading and updating (unprotected) shared variables, presuming the access is properly synchronized through some other kind of task interaction.

and you are not doing any form of synchronization, so the system can do what it feels like; the results aren’t defined by the language. In similar circumstances I’ve seen one task outputting “hello” and another outputting “world” resulting in “hweolrllod”.

Comment: @Simon Wright in Linux OS put_line which is similar to '\n' in c ,In worst case some time line doesn't print on screen so here '\n' helps to flush from stdout buffer to screen but if it was so as u said above then why not its printing in the same formate  when put_line is replace with put?

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking. I think terminal output is line-buffered, so nothing appears on screen until the newline is seen; but exactly what happens inside the terminal output routines in the OS isn’t something you ought to rely on, especially if you want your code to be portable between OSs/compilers. You appear to be seeing a difference between `put_line (“foo”);` and `put (“foo”); new_line;`, which doesn’t surprise me in the slightest.

Comment: @SimonWrigh you mention above that " it turns out that put_line involves blocking" what if i use only 'put' then will i get output as expected i.e second.start will finish all its execution than only other execution will happen is that guarantee?

Comment: On Mac OS X, using just `put` results in a single long line with “first” and “second” intermingled just as in the `put_line` case.